# Is all mankind suppose to reach the level of the Tzadick

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mysticism-kabbalah, reincarnation

In the cycle of reincarnation is every one to reincarnate until they reach the level of Tzadick or simply until they fulfill the Mitzvot?

Comment: By definition a tzaddik is one who fulfills the mitzvot.

Comment: @N.T. Not exactly. There are many mitzvos one cannot do nowadays

Comment: @mroll Obviously I meant the available mitzvot.

Comment: There are certain mitzvot that are equated with all the mitzvot, like Shabbat, tzitzit and tefillin. When those are fulfilled appropriately, one is also fulfilling all the other mitzvot, even those which may not be available in a separate manner. Another principle in Torah is that when one does not have access to the physical material fulfillment of any given Mitzvah, one can fulfill by learning that Mitzvah as it is found in the written and oral Torah. This relates to the principle that the words of Torah made through the utterances of our lips are equated to “small/immature action “.

Answer (score 1):

Gershom Scholem (Kabbalah, p. 347) wrote:

> In the Bahir it is stated that transmigration may continue for 1,000
> generations, but the common opinion in the Spanish Kabbalah is that in
> order to atone for its sins, the soul transmigrates three more times
> after entering its original body (according to Job 33 :29, "Behold,
> God does all these things, twice, three times, with a man"). However,
> the righteous transmigrate endlessly for the benefit of the universe,
> not for their own benefit. As on all points of this doctrine, opposing
> views also exist in kabbalistic literature: the righteous transmigrate
> as many as three times, the wicked, as many as 1,000.

It seems that between the various theories of reincarnation there is not a consistent answer to this question. Perhaps it would be better to ask about how a specific kabbalistic system (e.g. Lurianic) would respond to this question.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer